# what kind of specific risks are arised when ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode is set to none

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, security, certificate

I'm using a WCF generated client to work with an Apache Axis (I think) web service. In order to get the communication to work properly, I had to set a lot of specif configuration, custom binding, certificates, etc.

Well, The stuff I bear in mind in order to perform authentication (with SOAP headers): I sign something (I think its the token) with my private key and the endpoint check back with my public key (I had to send my public key to the service first). Its the same thing for the service endpoint: the service has to check the authentication using my public key.

So, they gave me their public certificate key to check if the endpoint is who it claims to be. There is an option in the settings 'ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode', so my question is what happens if I set this option as 'none'? What kind of specific risks could arise when this option is set? 
For example: if the connection is made by a proxy, it could be possible for this proxy to supplant the service to which I'm sending requests?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

If you disable the certificate validation, by setting the  `ServiceCertificate.Authentication.` `CertificateValidationMode` to `none` then your application (client) will be vulnerable to "man-in-the-middle" attacks.
Without validation, your application will not be able to determine the identity of the server, so the client cannot be sure the endpoint is the real site.

Rather than disabling the SSL certificate validation, you may want to set the `CertificateValidationMode` to `PeerOrChainTrust` in which "The certificate is valid if it is in the trusted people store, or if the chain builds to a certification authority in the trusted root store."
In that way, if the certificate is from a valid third party (Verisign), you can rely on the certificate chain to verify just the root certificate. Otherwise, you can import the server certificate into the certificate store's "Trusted People".

Comment: In other words, setting it to `none` makes it almost the same as if there was no certificate at all.